# How to add npm keywords without publishing?

Tags: npm, npm-publish, npm-cli

I just added some `keywords` to my `package.json` file for my package on npm. Is it possible to make npm show these updates without publishing a new version?
I think doing `npm patch` for a simple change like this is not needed  or maybe I'm wrong?